# Combining two list in lisp to output certain item

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I currently have solved the rucksack problem and and have two lists like below

List 1 ((hat 10 5) (clothes 10 10) (tent 40 70) )

List 2 (((1 1 1).0) ((1 0 1) .23) ((1 0 0) .45) ((0 0 0) .0))

List 2 represent if item is taken or not.((1 1 1) .0) means all items taken and 0 represents how useful it is. My final output is binary but I'm wondering how I can create a function that takes the two list and displays the actual item like the example below

Instead of printing ((1 0 1) .23)
Print ((hat tent) . 23))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you've got a list that's essentially a mask, and a list of items of the same length, and for each element of the mask, you want to collect something from the corresponding item in the list of items.  I'm not sure what the best name for such a function is, but here's an implementation that calls it **decode**:

```
(defun decode (mask items &key (key 'identity) (test 'identity))
  (loop
     for bit in mask
     for item in items
     when (funcall test bit)
     collect (funcall key item)))
```

```
CL-USER> (decode '(nil t nil nil t) '(a b c d e))
; (B E)
CL-USER> (decode '(nil t nil nil t) '(a b c d e) :key 'symbol-name)
; ("B" "E")
CL-USER> (decode '(nil t nil nil t) '(a b c d e) :test 'null)
; (A C D)
```

It's not hard to apply that to your use case;  the test is whether the mask element is non-zero, and the key function is **first**, since you want the name of the item:

```
(defparameter *items*
  '((hat 10 5) (clothes 10 10) (tent 40 70)))

(defparameter *solutions*
  '(((1 1 1) . 0) ((1 0 1) . 23) ((1 0 0) . 45) ((0 0 0) . 0)))

(decode '(1 0 1) *items*
        :key 'first
        :test (complement #'zerop))
;;=> (hat tent)

(mapcar #'(lambda (solution)
            (cons (decode (car solution)
                          *items*
                          :key 'first
                          :test (complement #'zerop))
                  (cdr solution)))
        *solutions*)
;;=> (((HAT CLOTHES TENT) . 0) ((HAT TENT) . 23) ((HAT) . 45) (NIL . 0))
```